# Laravel : Search with ajax ,route don't work correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, routes, controller

I have Laravel web App contain search on database .
first I have this input :

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"  id="search_me" placeholder="{{__('home.Search')}}" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="hidden" id="course_id" value="{{$course->id}}">
```

so I create this JavaScript function :

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var search_me=document.getElementById('search_me').value;
            var id=document.getElementById('course_id').value;

                    $.ajax({
                        method : 'POST',
                        url : "{{route ('search')}}",
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data:{
                            '_token':'{{csrf_token()}}',
                            'search_data':search_me , 
                            'course_id':id,
                            },
                        
                        success:function(data){
                        console.log(data); 
                        }
                    });  
        }
</script>
```

then I create the route like this :

```
Route::get('/search', [App\Http\Controllers\user\User_controller::class, 'search_data'])->name('search');
```

and the controller method of :

```
public function search_data(Request $request)
{
        $output="";
        $questions = Question::table('questions')->where('course_id',$request->course_id)->where('question' ,'LIKE' ,'%'.$request->search_data."%")->get();
        return json_nencode($questions);

}
```

when I type on the text input I get error :

```
main.js?attr=DEbA4C86cFywU9oORVUcm4fay4bVMB7MeKBvEkL0Iy2jpADxMlMEszxyl6A-4lWVGp58XG2e-YEmLqgl2mGpQg:1078 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ku/search 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

inside this error I found this :

```
        return fun.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
```

I followed many examples like this ,I don't know where is my error ?

### Update

I made some changes :
I change ajax request to :

```
var route = 'route("search"'+'/'+search_me+'/'+id;
     $.get("{{"+route+"}}", function(data,status){
                    console.log( data );
                });
```

also I change the route to get.
then I change the controller to :

```
public function search_data($search , $id)
    {

            $output="";
            $questions = Question::table('questions')->where('course_id',$id)->where('question' ,'LIKE' ,'%'.$search."%")->get();
            return json_nencode($questions);
    }
```

Now when I keyup the Input text I get this :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully I solved it by this way :
the route :

```
Route::get('/search'.'/{search}/{course}', [App\Http\Controllers\user\User_controller::class, 'search_data'])->name('search');
```

the js function :

```
function myFunction(id) {
            var search_me=document.getElementById('search_me').value;
            var route = "{{URL::to('search')}}"+'/'+search_me+'/'+id;
            if(search_me != ""){
                $.get(route, function(data,status){
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your ajax method is `post` but your route is `get`

change route to `post`

```
Route::post('/search', [App\Http\Controllers\user\User_controller::class, 'search_data'])->name('search');
```

or your ajax to `get`

```
                  $.ajax({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : "{{route ('search')}}",
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data:{
                            'search_data':search_me , 
                            'course_id':id,
                            },
                        
                        success:function(data){
                        console.log(data); 
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: this is your route ```Route::get('/search', [App\Http\Controllers\user\User_controller::class, 'search_data'])->name('search');``` and your ajax is using ```post``` method how do you say its true?

Comment: you said true , I said it was my mistake it was post but I changed it to get then copied id

Comment: type ```php artisan route:list``` then find the route and post it here for me to see

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code before using $.ajax request

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
   }
});
```

let me know if it helps and it's also documented on the official laravel docs.
here is the [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

after this, you don't need to add __token inside the $.ajax request.

Comment: I put it before ajax request ,I get this : ReferenceError: beayMLh3LrjWSAvKQRuTm465iMGmMaJUKM2h8Oqg is not defined

Comment: I have updated my response, there was a mistake in previous